# Como limpar linhas no pandas utilizando uma lista como filtro?

Tags: python, pandas

Dado o df como o indicado abaixo (poderia ser um bem maior), gostaria de deletar no df  os dados das linhas em função da lista 'listaFiltro'.

```
nome = ['foo','bar','fiz','zaz','foo','far','bar','fiz','cdd','boo','zuz','zuz']
valor = [2,3,2,5,6,7,2,9,6,3,8,10]

listaFiltro = ['zuz', 'boo']

df = pd.DataFrame({'nome': nome, 'valor': valor})
```

```
    nome    valor
0   foo     2
1   bar     3
2   fiz     2
3   zaz     5
4   foo     6
5   far     7
6   bar     2
7   fiz     9
8   cdd     6
9   boo     3
10  zuz     8
11  zuz     10
```

Já tentei utilizar dessa forma aqui mas sem sucesso:

```
df = df.drop(df[df.nome] != listaFiltro.index)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fazendo o import e criando as listas com os valores:

```
import pandas as pd

nome = ['foo','bar','fiz','zaz','foo','far','bar','fiz','cdd','boo','zuz','zuz']
valor = [2,3,2,5,6,7,2,9,6,3,8,10]

listaFiltro = ['zuz', 'boo']
```

Criando o data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nome': nome, 'valor': valor})
```

Mantendo somente os valores que não estão na listaFiltro:

```
df1 = df[~df['nome'].isin(listaFiltro)]
df1
```

O sinal ~ indica os valores que **não estão** dentro do filtro.
É sempre uma boa prática criar data frame novo quando for fazer alteração, dessa forma você sempre mantém o data frame principal intacto.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme demonstra [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960116/12114971), você pode utilizar o [pandas.DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

```
df = df[~df['nome'].isin(listaFiltro)]
```

Com esse comando, você está substituindo o seu dataframe `df` pelo dataframe `df` onde os valores da coluna `nome` não estejam em `listaFiltro`.